# さんかいの工スカレ一タ一でおります

Tags: particle-の

Is it natural to say “さんかいの工スカレ一タ一でおります”??

My concept is there is individual escalator for every floor. Now I am on 3rd floor and take it down to any lower floor I want. So, I use の to indicate I am taking the 3rd floor eacalator and going down. Only focus the “down” action, not indicating which floor I'm going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> さんかいの工スカレ一タ一でおります or 三階｛さんかい｝のエスカレーターで下｛お｝ります

Basically, I think, Naruto's answer is perfect.
We could use 三階からエスカレーターで下ります in your case.

Anyway we usually simply say エスカレーターで下ります omitting 三階から, because the floor where you are now is useless in the conversation.

But, we also use 三階 **の** エスカレーターで下ります. It doesn't sound odd if you know the proper case where it is used.
I'll show you the cases where we use it.

1. We also use commonly 三階 **の** エスカレーターで下ります, when the escalator service is available only on some floors including the 3rd floor. In this case, the phrase implies 三階で利用｛りよう｝できるエスカレーターで下｛お｝ります or 三階で乗｛の｝れるエスカレーターで下｛お｝ります。
   For the same reason, we use 三階 **の** エレベーターで下｛お｝ります. As you know, elevators do not always stop at every floor, especially in a large building or like that.
2. When you have several ways available on the 3rd floor besides the escalator to go downwards, you usually say 三階｛さんかい｝ **の** エスカレーターで下｛お｝ります or simply エスカレーターで下｛お｝ります. This is especially useful to the partner waiting for you on the lower floor. By this phrase, the partner could get information about where he/she should wait for you.
   In this case, 三階｛さんかい｝ **の** エスカレーターで下｛お｝ります implies 三階｛さんかい｝ **の** エスカレーターを利用｛りよう｝して下｛お｝ります.
   We also say 三階 **の** 階段｛かいだん｝を使｛つか｝って下｛お｝ります

As a whole, the difference between 三階からエスカレーターで下ります and 三階のエスカレーターで下ります is like:

- 三階からエスカレーターで下ります: *I'm going to take the escalator to go downwards from the 3rd floor.*
- 三階のエスカレーターで下ります: *I'm going to take the escalator accessible from the 3rd floor to go downwards.*

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you say 三階【さんかい】**から**エスカレーターで下【お】ります。 (から ≒ "from")

三階のエスカレーター is not entirely wrong, but it sounds odd to me because escalators are placed *between* floors, not at individual floors.

If you want to specify the destination floor, you can use both に and へ to mark it. (e.g, 三階から一階にエスカレーターで下ります)

Comment: thanks! I noticed that you mentioned (から ≒ "from"). Does it mean that から means from? And, 三階から一階にエスカレーターで下ります = take the 3rd floor escalator to 1st floor?

Comment: Yes, roughly speaking, から means *from*. 三階から一階にエスカレーターで下ります literally means "(I) go down from the 3rd floor to the 1st floor using the escalators."